# "[Process ID] i8042: No controller found" message during boot just after GRUB

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia

The last 6 months have been a saga with my main computer, and as a result the motherboard, one of the processors, and the video card have all been replaced under warranty. I've just got it running again.

It's not 100% over yet: During boot, just after the GRUB options screen, I get the message:

"**[  some ID number which changes each time] i8042: No controller found**"

[image]

It sits there unchanged for about 30 seconds before boot is completed.

Relevant notes:

I was using a basic video card (GT218 aka GT 220) for which I used the Nouveau driver while waiting for my replacement GT 730 to arrive. The message did not appear while this card was installed.

Edit: Incorrect
*Upon receiving the replacement GT 730, I installed the card using the Nouveau driver and the "No controller found" message appeared again during every boot.*

Edit: Correct
*I had been told by the fellow who originally installed the replacement GT 730 that it didn't have a working driver - I was surprised as the Nouveau driver was still in use and I expected it to work with this card. He gave the computer back to me with the GT218 (aka GT 220) installed using the Nouveau driver. When I got home, I installed the NVIDIA 352 driver, then shut the computer down and took the GT218 (aka GT 220) out and put the GT 730 in. I never tried the GT 730 with the Nouveau driver myself.*

This morning I installed the NVIDIA 352 driver so that I could install and run CUDA software. The "No controller found" message appears every time I boot.

There seem to be a million other questions regarding this issue, but I'm afraid I haven't found anything that helps me resolve the problem.

Comment: I just got a little bit more information about this problem, but not enough for me to be able to fix the problem.

I took a photo of the message during boot, and then searched for that item in `syslog` - I found it and took a screenshot of it. I would love to add those two pictures here, but I can't work out how. I'll Imgur them:

http://imgur.com/a/pHXSN

Comment: This mystery remains unsolved. This question is no longer relevant, because I ran the distribution upgrade this morning from 14.04 to 16.04, and it seems to have worked. The “[Process ID] i8042: No controller found” message doesn't appear any more.